# How to check if a rectangle is intersecting?

Tags: java, graphics2d

Hi I am trying to make this constructor: `public Rectangle createIntersection(Rectangle r){ ....` to return a new Rectangle object representing the intersection of this Rectangle with the specified Rectangle.

So far I have done this for the constructor, but I am not sure if it is correct:

```
public Rectangle createIntersection(Rectangle r) { 
   Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle () ; 
   Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle ();
   r2.setRect(r);
   r2.createIntersection(r1); 
   return r2;
}
```

Then I am supposed to create this constructor `public Boolean intersects (Rectangle r)` to return true if this intersect the specified Rectangle and return false if not. They are said to intersect if their interiors overlap. So I know for this that I need to use the four instance variables, I have been using (int x int y int height and int width). I know it has to figure out if it is intersecting by doing `x + width` and if this value is less than the point across from it then the rectangles are overlapping. I'm not sure how to write this.

Comment: `"I am trying to make this constructor: public Rectangle createIntersection(Rectangle r){ ...."` -- this is not a constructor. Please clarify.

Comment: This function won't ever return.

Comment: Hint: do the math first. Sit down with a pen and a piece of paper. Draw rectangles manually; and see if you can figure the different categories of possible intersections (if i dont get it wrong, there are just three different cases you need to worry about). So, create an "algorithm"; and when that works on paper; try to put it into code. Don't try to solve the programming puzzle whilst you have no idea how the math is supposed to work out. You don't learn to juggle whilst you are learning to ride the unicycle either, do you?

Comment: Why? [`java.awt.Rectangle.createIntersection()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#createIntersection-java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D-) already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method returns the overlapping area of two rectangles, or null if they do not overlap:

```
 public static Rectangle createIntersection(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2) {

     // Left x
     int leftX = Math.max(r1.x, r2.x);

     // Right x
     int rightX = (int) Math.min(r1.getMaxX(), r2.getMaxX());

     // TopY
     int topY = Math.max(r1.y,r2.y);

     // Bottom y
     int botY =  (int) Math.min(r1.getMaxY(), r2.getMaxY());

     if ((rightX > leftX) && (botY > topY)) {
         return new Rectangle(leftX, topY, (rightX - leftX), (botY -topY));
     }

     return null;
 }
```

Some testing :

```
 public static void main(String [] args) {

        Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(10,10,10,10);
        Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(10,10,10,10);
        System.out.println(createIntersection(r1, r2));

        r1 = new Rectangle(10,10,10,10);
        r2 = new Rectangle(15,15,10,10);
        System.out.println(createIntersection(r1, r2));

        r1 = new Rectangle(20,20,10,10);
        r2 = new Rectangle(15,15,10,10);
        System.out.println(createIntersection(r1, r2));

        r1 = new Rectangle(15,30,10,10);
        r2 = new Rectangle(15,15,10,10);
        System.out.println(createIntersection(r1, r2));

        r1 = new Rectangle(15,30,10,10);
        r2 = new Rectangle(15,15,10,20);
        System.out.println(createIntersection(r1, r2));
 }
```

Don't hesitate to ask if the code is not clear.

Comment: Good Evening. I didn't downvote; but after thinking about it for a while; I think that your solution is simply not correct.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Can you say what is wrong with it ? (BTW if you you think it should be down voted don't hesitate (0: )

Comment: Hmm. Now that I have a closer look ... not so sure any more. I might have overlooked that you are calling getMaxX(), but use the min of that.  Probably your algorithm is correct. Ah, whatever.

Comment: I did run (and post) some additional tests. I hope the OP will test is further and give feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are mixing up things. You are talking of constructors; but what you makes sense here; are ordinary member methods of your rectangle class!

The first thing that you want to code is something like:

```
class Rectangle {
 ...
 public boolean intersects(Rectangle other) {
   // should return true if "this" and "other" rectangle "intersect"
   return intersectsOnX(other.x, other.width) && intersectsOnY(other.y, other.height);
 }

 private boolean intersectsOnX(int otherX, int otherWidth) {
   // check if other starts to the right of this
   if (this.x + width <= otherX) return false;
   // check if this starts to the left of other
   if (otherX + otherWidth <= this.x) return false;
   // then this / other must be overlapping 
   return true;
}
```

*intersectsOnY()* works the same way (actually it would be using the very same comparisons; so you would actually want to avoid the code duplication there.

Now, someone could call intersects() to understand if there is an intersection; and if that method returns true; you one could call that other method you should put into the Rectangle class:

```
public Rectangle getIntersection(Rectangle other) {
```

The above is meant as starting point for you - as I commented: it is not too hard to solve this; so just give it a try.

Comment: The PO maybe thinking of extending `java.awt.Rectangle` by adding the intersection functionality.